# Detecting collision in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, collision

As I understand the way that collision works in the Swift SpriteKit; you identify a combination of bit masks, identifying what can collide with what, and you handle an event called `didBegin`.  Here's my version of the method:

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    print("test")
    print (contact.bodyA.node?.name)
    print (contact.bodyB.node?.name)
}
```

I've then set a bit mask up for three separate categories:

```
private let collisionAlien : UInt32 = 1 << 0
private let collisionBullet : UInt32 = 1 << 1
private let collisionPlayer : UInt32 = 1 << 2
```

Which, as I understand it, should result in:

```
...001
...010
...100
```

Finally, I've set the category of each of the screen elements:

```
player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = collisionPlayer
player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0
```

...

```
alien.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = collisionAlien
alien.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
alien.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = collisionPlayer
```

My understanding is that, when an alien makes contact with the player, the event should fire, but no physical interaction should occur between the two.  Whilst the latter is true (the objects pass through each other), the former is not.  The event does not fire.

Clearly I've misunderstood something fundamental about this interaction.  How can I get the event in question to fire when, for example, the alien intersects the player?

Comment: What you have looks OK to me. Is your didBegin(contact) method in a class that conforms to SKPhysicsContactDelegate and have you set your SKPhysicsWorld's contactDelegate to point to it?

Comment: Ah - yes... and no - adding self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self fixed it for me - thanks!